# ORA-00936: missing expression - what is the cause?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

in Oracle SQL Developer I am runing :

```
SELECT 'XYZ' , * FROM ALL_TABLES ;
```

and get this error:

> `ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 14 Column: 14`

it  runs fine when I run:

```
 SELECT 'XYZ' , * FROM ALL_TABLES ;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your second query is 100% identical to the first. I assume you meant `SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES` ?

Comment: yes you are right : the second query was without the string expression :  SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to combine `*` with an additional column in your `SELECT` clause, you have to use a table alias:

```
 SELECT 'XYZ' , at.* FROM ALL_TABLES at;
```

Comment: thanks Frank, it works;   is that to avoid confusion ?    I take it as  a rule of thumb:  "use table aliases whenever it came to use with expressions"